# The New Auth Dialog - how do you get it to display?

Tags: facebook, oauth

How do you enable the new auth dialog for facebook apps?  I have a website that is using FB authentication and I can't get it to show the new Auth dialog.

I have tried both server and client authentication flow and no luck getting the new Auth dialog to show :(.

This link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/  says to Enable the Enhanced Auth Dialog but I don't see an option to Enable?

This link http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/633/ talks about enabling the Auth Dialog also but not how to do it.

I have edited my app and setup all of the basic information, the Auth Dialog information and the Advanced information I did not change.     My app is not in Sandbox mode.

What am I missing?

**Update (11:00 pm CST):**

I created another FB App and it immediately shows the new oAuth dialog.   So I went in and compared the settings on my new FB App vs my old FB App.

Of course my new FB App has less advanced settings then the new FB App :(.

The new FB app has the following settings under the Apps -->Advanced-->Migrations section
  These are the default settings:

- Stream post URL security   (disabled)
- Remove offline_access permission  (enabled)
- Forces use of login secret for auth.login  (disabled)
- August 2012 breaking changes  (enabled)
- September 2012 breaking changes  (enabled)
- October 2012 breaking changes.  (enabled).

  The FB app that does not show the OAuth Dialog has these extra settings in the Advanced-Migrations settings.
- Include Checkins with Statuses (disabled)
- External Page Migration (disabled)

  It would be great if anyone from FB could respond to what is happening.  I didn't create the application that is not showing the OAuth dialog very long ago.

  Why does the one I just create work?

  What should all the settings be for my App to show the OAuth dialog?

  Thanks,

Comment: I would check app settings again.

Comment: @GilBirman:  What app settings specifically would you check?

Comment: It used to be in Settings>Advanced. However, Facebook supposedly migrated everyone to it. `On February 1, 2012, all apps will be enabled for the improved dialog, but those that haven’t fully configured their dialog can disable the setting in the Developer App until February 15, at which time it will be turned on for all apps.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and used the client side authentication flow and the new oAuth dialog is showing for me now.